# Is the name of function a pointer variable?

Tags: c

My first doubt is:

Is the name of function a pointer variable and Which variable's address is the pointer  holding ? (in this program which variable's address addition pointer holds).

AND
if i write '&' before addition,  program runs fine. Is compiler automatically add '&' during compilation ???

```
#include<stdio.h>
int addition(int, int);
int main() 
{
int (*p)(int, int);
int sum;
p=addition;  // if I add '&'  before function name the            
//program runs fine. (&addition).
sum=p(10, 20);
printf("Sum is %d\n", sum);
return 0;
} 
int addition(int x, int y)
{
int r;
r=x+y;
return r;
}
```

Output is: Sum is 30.

Comment: Next please be so kind to format you sources in a more readable manner: Using a proper indention is common sense.

Comment: DV for formatting/indentation.

Comment: What problem do you face while reading. which part is not easily readable to you. I want to know so I can improve myself.

Answer (score 3):

In C, using the name of a function in a value context implicitly gives the address of that function.  There is nothing else that it could give, so this is a convenience.  But using an explicit `&` in front also works, as you have discovered.  The result is the same either way.

Answer (score 2):

`int (*p)(int, int);`

Here you are declaring a pointer to a function.

In  `p = addition;`
You are pointing `p` to `addition` function.
Just as variables which are declared have  addresses, functions too have their own addresses.
So, by doing that you are assigning the address of `addition` to `p` and thus `p` points to `addition` function.

Hope this explanation clears your doubts.

Just like arrays, assigning a function name or address of the function to a pointer variable is the same.
so your choice to place a `&` before addition.

Answer (score 1):

Function names are pointer-like and function pointers are function-like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void hw(void) { puts("hello world"); }
int main()
{
    /*all three work*/
    hw();
    (&hw)();
    (*&hw)();
}
```

That makes them a little bit like arrays in that they autoconvert to pointers and that you can't really get
to the "value" of a function (a block of op codes), which is because 
C doesn't have any operations on it.

The difference between functions and function pointers is blurred 
in most contexts in C, but it does come up if you `typedef`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef void void_void_t(void);      //a function typedef
typedef void (*void_void_pt)(void);  //a function pointer typedef
void_void_t hw;  //no storage, only verifies that hw matches the signature
void_void_pt hwp; //a null pointer of the void_void_pt type; takes up memory
void hw(void) { puts("hello world"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of a function is not a pointer.   What you're seeing is a result of how expressions work in C.

However, when used in an expression like

```
 p = addition;
```

the name of the function is implicitly converted to a pointer.   In this context,  `p = addition` (which implicitly converts `addition` to a pointer, and assigns the result to `p`) and `p = &addition` (which computes a pointer with the same value, and assigns the result to `p`) have the same net effect.